# Battery Capacity decreased after update

Tags: battery, asus-laptop

I just updated the bios of my Asus X556UQ Laptop. But After the update the battery capacity decreased. I don't know why!

**Battery Capacity History before update**:

[Battery Capacity History before update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8uje.jpg)

**Battery Capacity After update**:

[Battery Capacity After update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Kdw4.jpg)

What's the solution?

Comment: Maybe try to calibrate your battery: https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1032745/

Comment: Why did you update the BIOS?  That's not something to do just because you want the latest and greatest firmware.  Were you having a specific issue?